# Parameter gets changed when passed in shell script

Tags: shell, alias, ksh

I am using ksh shell. I have to fetch info from the defined alias, I am using below code

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
source ~/.profile
echo "parameter : $1"
alias | grep hello
```

I have saved the above script as test.sh
or running test.sh, I am getting below output :

```
./test 324 
parameter : autologout
hello='Hello, How are you'
```

My issue is, when I passed 324 as parameter, why autologout is coming as `$1` ?
How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just save parameter `$1` before doing `source` which might change your **positional parameters**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

arg1="$1"
source ~/.profile
echo "parameter : $arg1"
alias | grep hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have a `set` command in your ~/.profile.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
source ~/.profile
set "new"
echo "parameter : $1"
alias | grep hello

>./script.ksh foo    
parameter : new
```

Now your parameter will always be "new".
Please try to comment out the `source` command and see if error still exists. If yes then search for `set` commands in your "~/.profile"